# Profile Image Bug - iPhone 5s

Tags: bug, design

I just randomly opened my profile tab, and saw this (on iPhone 5s):

[image: Profile bug pic]

What is going on?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Are you still seeing this problem?

Comment: @Jin It was recently fixed